# Linq to Entities strange deploying behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hi I started building apps with this technology and I am facing a weird problem... on some machines I need to add theese lines to the app.config to get to work:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

while in other machines it runs well without theese lines.... the thing is that when I add theese lines the app wont run on machines that did not needed theese lines in the firs place, and I would like not to publish to versions of the app, is there a way to solve this?

Any Help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would post as comment but i can't yet.**

It could be your machine.configs are different.  I would check to make sure your DbProviderFactories are registered consistently in the machine.config.

Comment: just read your last comment, then your user name... as part of the comment.  Too funny...

Comment: can you please expand your answer to Instructions on how to do what you suggest?

Comment: Did you check your configs?  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config ?  Make sure they are consistant?  And did you see my post below?

Comment: you did not see my other comments??? you do not deserve the bounty and yet you are getting it.... sad =(

Comment: What is the problem?  Which comment are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing it?

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```